# db4o in a class without context android - java

Tags: java, android, db4o

I'm using a db4oHelper in the main activity without problem but when i want use de db in a  class without context I've problems.. This class doesn't extends of Activity..

```
public void actualizatrat(Context context){
    dbHelper();
    db4oHelper.deleteAll();
    //...
}

private Db4oHelper dbHelper() {
if (db4oHelper == null) {
        db4oHelper = new Db4oHelper(this);
        db4oHelper.db();
    }
    return db4oHelper;
}
```

the constructor `db4oHelper`:

```
    public Db4oHelper(Context ctx)
    {
          context = ctx;
    }
```

Eclipse shows the error: The constructor `Db4oHelper`(Actualiza) is undefined

can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the class you want to have access to the helper may not be a `Context` itself, you likely created it from one of the above components that does, so just pass the `Context` you have forward.

```
public void actualizatrat(Context context){
    dbHelper(context);
    db4oHelper.deleteAll();
    (...)
}

private Db4oHelper dbHelper(Context context) {
    if (db4oHelper == null) {
        db4oHelper = new Db4oHelper(context);
        db4oHelper.db();
    }
    return db4oHelper;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest getting the Application context instead. Have a look here:

[Static way to get 'Context' on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android)